# How CloudKit treat recursive operations?

Tags: ios, recursion, cloudkit

`CKContainer's` `performQuery` method get called recursively as a depth-first search, and at the 5th level it does not return. What can I do, why it happens? Is it a CloudKit limitation about the depth of stack of threads? Is it any documentation about it? Have you met with similar?

```
func sth() {
    // init here entityName, predicate..
    publicDatabase.performQuery(CKQuery(recordType: entityName, predicate: predicate), inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: {records, error in

        if error == nil {  //at 5th level neither this line ..

            let temporaryContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
            temporaryContext.parentContext = Utility.managedObjectContext()
            temporaryContext.performBlockAndWait({

                sth()
            })
        } else {
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema)
    })
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    println("log 2") // nor that line is get reached
}
```